# Different PHP results between base64_encode and convert.base64-encode

Tags: php

In PHP, it exists two ways to encode content in base64. We can use function [`base64_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) which takes a string or use the string filter [`convert.base64-encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/filters.convert.php)  to use with a stream. But I can't produce the same result with these two methods.

```php
<?php

$content = "foo";

$encoded1 = base64_encode($content);

$stream = tmpfile();

stream_filter_append($stream, 'convert.base64-encode');

fwrite($stream, $content);
fseek($stream, 0);

$encoded2 = stream_get_contents($stream);

echo sprintf(
    "Content encoded with base64_encode(): %s\nContent encoded with convert.base64-encode filter: %s\n",
    $encoded1,
    $encoded2,
);
```

**Output**

```
Content encoded with base64_encode(): Zm9v
Content encoded with convert.base64-encode filter: Wm05dg==
```

In the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filters.convert.php), this citation can be read.

> Use of these filters are equivalent to processing all stream data through the base64_encode() and base64_decode() functions respectively.

Comment: Do they decode the same?

Comment: It seems to an issue with `stream_get_contents()`, that leads to double encoding. If you look directly into the file, the content is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the stream filter appends itself in read/write mode, so reading the file again without closing the handle would apply base64 one more time; in your case, you only want the filter to apply when writing.

A simple fix:

```php
stream_filter_append($fp, "convert.base64-encode", STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
```

This is also discussed in [one of the examples](https://www.php.net/stream_filter_append#example-5011) of the manual.

Comment: I understand your explanation Thanks for this solution !